# Iterating through columns in excel and comparing cells

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have two columns and I want to compare each cell with its adjacent cell and increment a variable 'count' each time there is a copy.

I have:

```
x = 0
for x in range(1, 10):
if created_closed[0][x] == created_closed[1][x]:
    count = count + 1

# print(created_closed[0][1])
# print(created_closed[1][1])
print(count)
```

I have attempted the two print statements that are commented and they both return the desired value. Now I want to iterate through each of the columns using iterator 'x' to compare. Along with that, increment count for each pair that are identical.

This is the error I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/U1111835/Documents/workday_data_analysis/analysis.py", line         29, in <module>
if created_closed[0][x] == created_closed[1][x]:
File "C:\Users\U1111835\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 767, in __getitem__
result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
File "C:\Users\U1111835\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-  packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3118, in get_value
tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 106, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 114, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 958, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 964, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 5
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: do you think you have `Key: 5` in the list? The error says it's not.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this.

When initializing created_closed:

```
created_closed = pd.read_excel(excel_document, usecols="Q,R", header=None).head()
```

Remove .head() in order to read the whole column

Comment: Please mark your chosen answer so the question can be finalised.